# Available resource based ThreadPool/Executor

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

Is there an existing Java Executor (like newCachedThreadPool) that will create and/or destroy Threads based on existing resources esp. memory?

For this example, I'm assuming that the Worker Threads will *always* have work to do, I'd just like to vary the Pool size depending on memory usage.

Comment: Strange idea, threads and pools them-self don't take lot of resources,  all depend on actual executing logic inside each worker.  If you add millions of keys to hash map inside worker, just the single instance of this worker will be enough to eat all memory.

Comment: @AlexChernyshev: Exactly my point. The Runnable Tasks take a certain amount of memory. I'd like a Pool/Executor to adjust how many tasks are run based on available memory. e.g. It won't execute a new Task if *used memory* > 80%.

Comment: I think better to add such check for free resources before pushing new task to executor. Because an executor needs to store pending tasks and wait for some condition (like yours used memory > 80% ) will happen, so it will eat resources even if won't start tasks.

Comment: Of course I can queue and dispatch ready Tasks based on resource availability. I don't want to "reinvent the wheel" though.